# HP Pavillion Laptop ACPI error on booting

Tags: boot, hp, acpi, 23.10

I have been running Ubuntu on my HP Pavilion Notebook - 15-p189sa for the last few years without any issues. I recently upgraded to the latest version of Ubuntu 23.10 (I believe) and since then I have been unable to boot the pc as I get spammed with the following error until I force power down the PC.

`ACPI Error no handler or method for gpe … Disabling event  (20230331/evgpe)` (manually copying this as I don’t know how to record it.

I have tried a fresh install from USB and various additions to the kernel such as `pci=nommconf` and `apci=strict` to no avail. When I try `apci=off` I get a blank screen.

If anyone knows of a way to fix this I would be very grateful!

Comment: If this error message does not affect any of your use cases, you can usually just ignore it.

Comment: The error prevents booting with an interminable stream of those errors until I turn off the pc using the power button. 
I’ve updated the post to clarify that

Comment: Try https://askubuntu.com/a/1373384 `acpi_mask_gpe=0x??` with the actual number you left out in "gpe ... Disabling"

Comment: I finally got around to trying this! Originally I thought it might just be GPE 65 but using my phone's slo mo camera I can read some others. I get errors for GPE 0A, 0B, 0C, (D, E, F), 60, 64 and 65.

Comment: Should I just add in a series of commands as mentioned in that post? `acpi_mask_gpe=0x0A, acpi_mask_gpe=0x0B ... etc.`
The battery on this laptop doesn't hold a charge anymore so I run it (or used to lol) while plugged in. Could these errors be associated with this?

Comment: Idk, if that will work, but it [also accepts a list](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/b555d191561a7f89b8d2108dff687d9bc4284e48/drivers/acpi/sysfs.c#L831), and you can [examine the syntax, which also supports ranges](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/b555d191561a7f89b8d2108dff687d9bc4284e48/lib/bitmap-str.c#L361), for example `=123-456,500`. You need to convert the hex to decimal, which you do by typing the `0x0a`, etc into a `python3` shell. It could indeed be battery-related, I get them as another error on mine, and I suggest removing the battery if you don't need it